# What is the optimal measuring time split for limited measuring time between signal+background and background in a Poisson counting experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mathematics, statistics, data-analysis

I’m trying to figure out the best split of time between measuring either background or signal+background in a counting experiment in the case where we have no prior knowledge about the mean signal count rate.

Assuming we have only a limited time T to perform measurements and there is no timing uncertainty.

Comment: this depends very much from the background to signal strength, so you should make a short measurement of the two, to determine it. if the signal strength is high, you take longer for the background , otherwise more for the combined measurement.

Comment: (+1) Adding a bit to what  @trula commented, the relative undesirability of false positives and false negatives may be a factor. If no answer is posted here, your question might get a good answer over at the stats stack exchange (there are many Poisson distribution questions and answers there) or at the signal processing stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to measure a flux, and not just trying to falsify a null hypothesis, I'd suggest equal time on background and signal+background. It's not optimum generally, but it's not far off optimum for any particular case.